# R function seas() not found in v.4.1.0

Tags: r, function

I have a script that I have used several times over the past year. The last time I used it was 3 months ago. It was all working with no errors.

In the interim, I have upgraded R to v. 4.1.0. This may be a generic problem, but I've covered what I think are the obvious possible explanations (packages not installed, libs not loaded, typos, etc).

Here's the relevant code (all calls are successful up to the seas() call):

```
library(fpp2)
library(ggplot2)
library(seasonal)
library(seas) # Added recently in attempt to mitigate this issue

hh=6
ff=12

LT <- read.csv("C:\\...\\lt.csv")

LTts <- ts(LT, start=c(2007,1),frequency=12)

#...

LTx11 <- seas(LTts, x11="")
```

RESULT (Console output):

```
> LTx11 <- seas(LTts, x11="")
#Error in seas(LTts, x11 = "") : could not find function "seas"
```

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see `seas` as a function exported by that package. Do you instead mean something like `mkseas` or similar? Where are you seeing `seas(.)` used/suggested? (Caveat all this with: I don't have the package installed, I'm just looking at the [package doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/seas/seas.pdf) and https://github.com/mwtoews/seas.)

Comment: Great questions. Thanks for looking. As I commented in the code, I only added the library(seas) code as an intuitive attempt to mitigate. I have no info on it and I am not sure how to go about searching for where to find the seas() function.

I _can_ tell you that with the other three libraries this call worked in the prior version of R. It all worked last time I used it, prior to upgrading to v.4.1.0 and removing the prior version. (v.4.x.x). So ... no, I don't mean mkseas or seasonal, but seas().

Btw, I'd love to know how to look at a library and see what functions are exposed. Googling

Comment: Okay, sorry, I don't know how to help here. I hope somebody else familiar with the package pops up.

Comment: @r2evans Here is my original instructional source for the seas() function. It apparently had been part of the seasonal library, which makes sense and I had included. I'm currently running down the links provided in this text from (Hyndman & Athanasopoulos)
https://otexts.com/fpp2/x11.html

Answer (score 1):

After digging around a little more, I found the original text reference where I had learned to use the seas() function in Hyndman's text:  https://otexts.com/fpp2/x11.html

In that text, I also found that seas() should be exposed by the seasonal library and verified this in the docs for that library.

After verifying this, added seasonal:: in front of the function and it worked. I wish I knew WHY this happened, but I don't. So here is the workaround.

Workaround:

```
LTx11 <- seasonal::seas(LTts, x11="")
```

If anyone can explain why this was necessary in v.4.1.0 and not earlier versions of R, please do!